# Multiple NGINX Ingresses with a single load balancer on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to setup Load Balancer on GCP with multiple Ingresses in different namespaces. I followed [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/save-on-your-aws-bill-with-kubernetes-ingress-148214a79dcb) followingly:

1. Created Cluster on GKE
2. Created [nginx-ingress Controller and a Service](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)
3. Created [nginx Ingress and a Service](https://gist.github.com/falnyr/1d15c43e5d660232bad33ca0cc694bcc) in a different namespace

Unfortunately, at this point, the service is unreachable leading to nginx-ingress Controller returning with HTTP 503.

I tried deploying the service in the same namespace as Ingress Controller and that is working fine. I suspect there could be issues with RBAC/ABAC setup?

Comment: Maybe it is not related but you should always set liveness and readiness probe to your workloads (deployments, statefulsets, etc). Are the rediscommander containers are ready when you `kubectl -n app-dev get pods` ?

Comment: You said "you deployed something to the same namespace as ingress controller". How's this possible? GKE hides the ingress controller from you. It won't show up as a pod to you.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google In the documentation, I am using this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml which creates namespace `ingress-nginx`. I am allowed to deploy into that namespace.

Comment: so, to be clear, GKE clusters DO come with an ingress controller built in, it uses GCP LB for each ingress resource you create. You shouldn't be restricted to only deploying within the same namespace as the nginx ingress controller. Do you have network policy or RBAC enabled?

Comment: Yeah you're using nginx-ingress not GKE ingress. I'm removing the GKE labels.

Comment: you should try the helm chart for nginx-controller. Then in the controller spec set type: LoadBalancer and it will create a load balancer, with default-backend, works for me.